# how to apply tooltip formatter in charts module drupal

Tags: drupal, charts, highcharts

I have to display 2 y-axis values in same popup.But I don't need that second y-axis value as series in graph plots.I have used chart module in drupal .How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: What Drupal module are you are referring to? Are standards Highcharts options not working? What is the code that you are using? Have you considered using [Highcharts Cloud](https://cloud.highcharts.com/) for Drupal? - [more info](http://www.highcharts.com/cloud/how-to-share-on-blogs-webpages/embed-in-drupal).

Answer (score 0):

See [Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/v58et0qe/)

You can do following :

Add your second series whose chart you don't want to show. make it visible : false as per code below. Second part is to create a variable which store your second series's data and  format your tooltip as per below code to get second series value in tooltip.

```
 var series2Data = [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5];
```

and in chart config do following:

```
            tooltip: { shared: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>';                
            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<span style="color:'+point.series.color+'">'+point.series.name+'</span>: <b>'+point.y+'</b><br/>'
                 s+='<br> Series2: ' + series2Data[i]  ;
            });

            return s;
        },
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
    visible:false,
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
```